# Can I re-open my popup after user grants permisisons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm testing edge cases for my chrome extension; handling cases where the user has not yet granted the permissions I need.

My popup calls chrome.identity.getAuthToken and, as expected, the user is show the chrome permissions screen and asked to approve.

But, as a side-effect, this closes my popup. I'd like to either keep the popup open, or re-open it after permission has been granted. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use an extension action popup instead of a tab or regular popup?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a regular popup.

My extension lets the user save info about the current tab. (You can think of it as a bookmark). I believe this needs to be in an extension, though it could be either a browser action or a page action.

Answer (score 1):

'Popup' is ambiguous.

A page action can be triggered dynamically using [chrome.pageAction.show(integer tabId)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-show).

A browser action cannot.

I don't know about `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` but e. g. `chrome.permissions.request` does not close a page action.

I don't think there is a way to stop it closing either. E. g. a [`beforeUnload` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) does not seem to work.

Comment: My extension is a browser action, not a page action. I could change that, but I don't think it will help. I think `chrom.pageAction.show` only shows/hides the icon of the page action; it does not bring up the popup.

chrome.permissions.request is for optional permissions.  I realize now that I had mis-spoken; I was not aware of all the issues.  The permissions I was talking about were those needed for oauth2 authentication with Google (scopes 'profile' and 'email').  The case I'm dealing with is the user removing these rights at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: @DavidGoldfarb regardless, there does not seem to be a way to do what you want